# Select * from view not showing all column

Tags: oracle, view, oracle-sqldeveloper

Good Day,

In Oracle using SQL Developer and Database 11g Express.

I have created a view and am trying to show the result of the view using

```
 SELECT *
 FROM ViewName;
```

That being said, not all columns are showing.  The last column does not show up.  If I change its location in the view, it does show up.

Code for View is as follows:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW SaleSummaryView AS
      SELECT      SALE.SaleID AS Sale_ID,
                  SALE.SaleDate AS Sale_Date,
                  SALE_ITEM.SaleItemID AS Sale_Item_ID,
                  SALE_ITEM.ItemID AS Item_ID,
                /*ITEM.ItemPrice AS Item_Price,*/
                  ITEM.ItemDescription AS Item_Descritption,
                  ITEM.ItemPrice AS Item_Price
      FROM        SALE JOIN SALE_ITEM
              ON  SALE.SaleID = SALE_ITEM.SaleID
                  JOIN ITEM
              ON  SALE_ITEM.ITEMID = ITEM.ITEMID;
```

You can see where I have tried moving its location in the view and it shows up.  In addition, I have tried running the following code:

```
 SELECT Item_Price
 FROM SaleSummaryView;
```

and it shows the values.

This is my first time using ORACLE and I have searched on YouTube and on StackOverflow but I can't seem to find the solution.

Comment: Did you try using the scroll bar at the bottom of the results window?

Comment: Yes.  God forgive me if I didn't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column was not showing up in the Script Output but was showing up in the Query Result.  Still not sure why, but I will close of the questions.

Comment: Oh - did you have some columns that were too wide, perhaps they were pushing the last column out of the page? You can control the formatting of columns (including width) in the Script Output, using the COLUMN command (from SQL\*Plus).

Comment: This is likely it.  I will play with it.  Thanks for the help I am trying to get better at not posting "bad" questions.

Comment: Posting "bad" questions is OK if they help you learn. This wasn't in the bottom 20% of bad questions anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure. Sql Devloper do prefetching of definition of some objects. And if you change something in the session (add new column to table) you have to refresh connection. (r-click on connection and refresh)